# Html.RenderAction with FileContentResult

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, filecontentresult

With MVC3, I have a controller that returns a FileContentResult, which is a JPEG. I can call this and it displays the JPEG perfectly in the browser.
I would like to display this multiple times on the page and the only reasonable way I can think of is using calling Html.RenderAction() multiple times within a view. This works for action methods that return ViewResult but not for this one that returns FileContentResult.

Error is
Compiler Error Message: CS1502: The best overloaded method match for 'System.Web.WebPages.WebPageExecutingBase.Write(System.Web.WebPages.HelperResult)' has some invalid arguments

What am I doing wrong?

Many thanks

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that you should use the `img` tag multiple times and point the URL to some CDN.

Answer (score 0):

Html.RenderAction is a void method, iirc, so it needs to be called like:

```
@{Html.RenderAction(..);}
```

or

```
<% Html.RenderAction(...); %>
```

if you're using webforms